# CodedUITests: Can i cancel a testrun when some requierements in ClassInitialize couldnt reached?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, mstest, coded-ui-tests

**is there a way to cancel a testrun in ClassInitialize()?** 
For example, i start the application i wanted to do some test with in my `ClassInitialize()` method. If the application couldnt be started i wanted to cancel the testrun and mark it as failure, to prevent the other steps like `TestInitialzie()` and the execution of the specific `TestMethod()`.
Is there any statement wich supports that?

or do i have to set a variable in `ClassInitialize()` and check this variable when it starts the `TestMethod()` and dependent from the value of the variable i mark the `TestMethod()` as failure or not?

**thanks in advance**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext TestContext)
{
    ...

    Assert.IsFalse(hasErrors, "Aborting {0}", TestContext.TestName);
}
```

Comment: there does not exists a method Assert.False in the Assert class at http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.aspx

Comment: The point is to use the Assert class on any way you want to fail the whole test run. Example: `Assert.IsTrue(applicationStarted(), "Aborting {0}", TestContext.TestName);`

Comment: yep thanks works like it should. I tried the same with Assert.Fail() but messed somewhere else something up i guess.. so i got some problems.